# Storing logs from log files inside /tmp folder to cloudwatch for lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Inside my lambda function I am using an external library which is generating logs. I am storing these log files in **/tmp** folder since otherwise I will need to change their code to start publishing the logs directly to cloudwatch. Since after the function is executed, I cannot access these logs anymore. I want to shift them from **/tmp/filename** to cloudwatch. 
To implement this, I am thinking that at the end of the function execution, I access those logs file and puts the log into cloudwatch. Can someone tell me that if there is something wrong with my approach or any better suggested approach to handle this case?

Comment: If you are storing the logs in /tmp in Lambda, you won't have access to view it. It basically indicates that you don't need your logs (because you can't access the Lambda containers). Instead of logging it to /tmp and then transferring to CloudWatch (which consumes time), why don't you write to CloudWatch directly?

Comment: Ironically if you just printed to `stdout` you'd not have to do anything.  Does your logging package not allow you to select the output file?